# How to extract the sequence matrix elements?

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

I have a matrix as shown in below:

```
A=[2;1;8;5;4;7]
```

now i need to extract the matrix A into 2 parts:

```
newpoint=[2];
rest=[1;8;5;4;7];
```

then apply loop again to extract the second column as new point :

```
newpoint=[1];
rest=[2;8;5;4;7];
```

Applying loop again to take third column number as new point :

```
newpoint=[8];
rest=[2;1;5;4;7];
```

Take the number in row sequence until the last row .
Can someone be kind enough to help.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that might do:

```
for i=1:length(A)    
    newpoint = A(i);
    if i==1
    rest = A(i+1:end);
    else
    if i== length(A);
    rest = A(1:end-1);
    else
    rest=A(1:i-1,i+1:end);

    ... stuff to do
end
```

Comment: You are mixing matlab syntax with syntax of other languages! Matlab uses `()` to access elements of vectors and matrices, not `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for something like this:

```
for i = 1:size(A,1)
    newpoint = A(i,1)
    rest = A;
    rest(i) = [];
    %# use rest and newpoint
end
```

Or if you prefer saving all the `rest` and `newpoint`s in a matrix:

```
newpoint = zeros(size(A,1),1);
rest = zeros(size(A,1)-1,size(A,1));
for i = 1:size(A,1)
    newpoint(i) = A(i,1);
    temp = A;
    temp(i) = [];
    rest(:,i) = temp;
end
```